# Send images through Worklight server without base64 encoding

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I want to upload image through worklight adapter in case of desktop browser and for IOS, android devices also, could you please suggest how we can post image through adapter. I find some example to post image as base 64 object.

Please provide me any reference by which we can upload image as multipart form data.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using JavaScript adapters in Worklight. You could perhaps do this using Cordova or AJAX, but I'm pretty sure you should use base64 encoding there as well.

The only other possibility for you to send binary is by using Java adapters.
Java adapters were introduced starting MobileFirst Platform (previously "Worklight") 7.0.

You can learn about Java adapters (basically a JAX-RS application), here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/adapter-framework-overview/

Comment: can you provide me the exact apis to send and receive binary images to java adapter.

Comment: There are no special MobileFirst APIs for this, as this is standard Java handling of binary files... please consult the Java API docs.